# How to create PDFs with automatic table layout in Java

Tags: java, pdf, tablelayout

In my application the user can configure their own table layouts to display the data on the screen, by choosing which colums in which order are to be shown. Now I want to give my users the possibility to export these tables to PDF. The tables should fill the page width completely and the columns should adjust their size depending on the content in the table, like e.g. HTML tables do.

Can you recomment a library or toolchain for this?

I checked Apache FOP, but their fo:tables do not support automatic table layout. Creating a Jasper Report dynamically also doesn't seem to fit, because I have to specify the exact column width there. So, does anyone have an idea how to achive this?

Open Source solutions with commercially friendly licenses like Apache or LGPL preferred.

**ANSWER:** There are no current tools that allow what I hoped for, so I mark this question as resolved.

Comment: I use iText, last free version is 2.1.7 which is fine for cases such as yours.

Comment: I used flying saucer in a project recently and it worked fantastically. If you like I can post some code samples. https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText is probably what you are looking for http://itextpdf.com/. Version 2.1.7 is free to use under the GPL lisence, for more info see this question [What is latest version of itext that is not AGPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl). It will work for you need, I would recommend using their code samples on their web page. Most are applicable to version 2.1.7 although it is currently on version 5.

I would recommend you take a look at Flying Saucer. It is an open source project that uses iText PDF as its core rendering engine but it allows you to define very dynamic xhtml files as your rendering medium.

Benefits of using FS+iText using iText by itself

- Allows for a much faster dev cycle for changes or new products
- Very easy to add in consistent and complex styles using a language built exactly for it (HTML + CSS)
- You can use the same HTML code to render your PDF as you use to view it online (if using web application)
- Can render graphics using `java.awt.Graphics` class onto the PDF, meaning you can integrate any graphics library with FS to paint objects like graphs onto your PDF.

Downsides:

- While it does a good job at rendering modern css styles it is not perfect. For instance when I used it the project required the `border-radius` style to be usable. It wasnt so I had to implement it.
- Rendering times and memory consumption are increased (Although I have found it to be quite fast and memory efficient)
- More libraires in your project.

Heres an example from the FS website if your ineterested.
https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-examples/src/main/java/PDFRender.java

Comment: Looks interesting, I will give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, but flying saucer while supporting HTML 5 does not support automatic table layout which I hoped. I now use a fixed table layout and use JasperReports to create the report, which even looks very nice when exported to Excel.

Comment: Accepted answer because best (and only) answer so far and AFAIK there is no solution for my problem.